# Avoid twitter stream from getting disconnected

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I have a python script that streams tweets into a csv file. I have provided the runtime parameter of 46800 seconds which is equal to 13 hrs, this dictates for how long the tweets have to be streamed into that csv. It was running fine for the specified duration until yesterday, but yesterday the script ran for 7.5 hrs only and it stopped streaming afterwards. I believe, there was no tweet about the topic i was streaming for a certain duration and hence the disconnect happened. So even if, when people started tweeting about the topic in question at later point, the connection didn't get re-establish and hence the script didn’t stream those tweets to csv file. So, i had to restart the script in another instance and let the script stream the tweets into another csv file. Today also, i ran into similar issue, the stream got disconnected after running for 6 hours and so i had to re-start again.

But i am not sure if that was the case. Below is the script that i used, please advise what could have happened. And if so, then how can i avoid this?

```
runtime = 46800

class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self,data):
 data1 = json.loads(data)
 time = data1["created_at"]
 tweet1 = BeautifulSoup(tweet, "lxml").get_text() 
 url = "https://twitter.com/{}/status/{}".format(data1["user"]["screen_name"], data1["id_str"])
 file = open('MARCH_DATA.csv', 'a')
 csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
 csv_writer.writerow([time, tweet1, url])
 file.close()

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret) 
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["MTA"], async = True)
time.sleep(runtime)
twitterStream.disconnect()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my streaming exercise.

```
# the regular imports, as well as this:
from urllib3.exceptions import ProtocolError

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret) 
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
while True:
        try:
            twitterStream.filter(track=["MTA"], async = True, stall_warnings=True)
        except (ProtocolError, AttributeError):
            continue
```